# Pyspark: Is there an equivalent method to pandas info()?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there an equivalent method to pandas info() method in PySpark?

I am trying to gain basic statistics about a dataframe in PySpark, such as:
Number of columns and rows
Number of nulls
Size of dataframe

Info() method in pandas provides all these statistics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also there is *summary* method to get row numbers and some other descritive statistics. It is similar to *describe* method already mentioned.

From PySpark [manual](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.summary):

```
df.summary().show()
+-------+------------------+-----+
|summary|               age| name|
+-------+------------------+-----+
|  count|                 2|    2|
|   mean|               3.5| null|
| stddev|2.1213203435596424| null|
|    min|                 2|Alice|
|    25%|                 2| null|
|    50%|                 2| null|
|    75%|                 5| null|
|    max|                 5|  Bob|
+-------+------------------+-----+

or

df.select("age", "name").summary("count").show()
+-------+---+----+
|summary|age|name|
+-------+---+----+
|  count|  2|   2|
+-------+---+----+
```

Comment: This is pandas describe() equivalent and not info() equivalent. For info() you just need to do a df.printSchema()

Answer (score 5):

To figure out type information about data frame you could try df.schema

```
spark.read.csv('matchCount.csv',header=True).printSchema()

StructType(List(StructField(categ,StringType,true),StructField(minv,StringType,true),StructField(maxv,StringType,true),StructField(counts,StringType,true),StructField(cutoff,StringType,true)))
```

For Summary stats you could also have a look at describe method from the documentation.

Comment: printSchema() will give you an easier to read version of the same info.

Comment: Please change the answer to use `printSchema()` :)

Answer (score 4):

I could not find a good answer so I use the slightly cheating

```
dataFrame.toPandas().info()
```

Comment: Have you tried this for a large data set? I'd expect that dataFrame.toPandas() will only work when the entire Spark dataframe can fit into memory on a single machine.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. Keep an eye on Koala's for the distributed implementation of the Panda's api - https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. If anyone has a better way of providing as much in-depth info as .info() I would like to know as it's one of the few Panda's methods I miss.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip re: koalas. I certainly will be watching that space.

Comment: With this answer you're just seeing the default pandas mapped types instead of the native spark types.

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44631639/9650685) answer to get a count of the null and not null values.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, when, count, col
import numpy as np

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1, None), (1, 2, float(5)), (1, 3, np.nan), (1, 4, None), (1, 5, float(10)), (1, 6, float('nan')), (1, 6, float('nan'))],
    ('session', "timestamp1", "id2"))

df.show()
# +-------+----------+----+
# |session|timestamp1| id2|
# +-------+----------+----+
# |      1|         1|null|
# |      1|         2| 5.0|
# |      1|         3| NaN|
# |      2|         4|null|
# |      1|         5|10.0|
# |      1|         6| NaN|
# |      1|         6| NaN|
# +-------+----------+----+

df.select([count(when(isnan(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
# +-------+----------+---+
# |session|timestamp1|id2|
# +-------+----------+---+
# |      0|         0|  3|
# +-------+----------+---+

df.select([count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
# +-------+----------+---+
# |session|timestamp1|id2|
# +-------+----------+---+
# |      0|         0|  5|
# +-------+----------+---+

df.describe().show()
# +-------+-------+------------------+---+
# |summary|session|        timestamp1|id2|
# +-------+-------+------------------+---+
# |  count|      7|                 7|  5|
# |   mean|    1.0| 3.857142857142857|NaN|
# | stddev|    0.0|1.9518001458970662|NaN|
# |    min|      1|                 1|5.0|
# |    max|      1|                 6|NaN|
# +-------+-------+------------------+---
```

There is no equivalent to `pandas.DataFrame.info()` that I know of.
`PrintSchema` is useful, and `toPandas.info()` works for small dataframes but  When I use `pandas.DataFrame.info()` I often look at the null values.

Comment: `isnan` does not support dtypes other than numeric types. The following is more general:

`df.select([F.sum(F.col(c).isNull().cast(T.IntegerType())).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()`

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a pyspark function that emulates Pandas.DataFrame.info()

```
from collections import Counter

def spark_info(df, abbreviate_columns=True, include_nested_types=False, count=None):
    """Similar to Pandas.DataFrame.info which produces output like:
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 201100 entries, 0 to 201099
    Columns: 151 entries, first_col to last_col
    dtypes: float64(20), int64(6), object(50)
    memory usage: 231.7+ MB
    """
    classinfo = "<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>"

    _cnt = count if count else df.count()
    numrows = f"Total Rows: {str(_cnt)}"

    _cols = (
        ', to '.join([
            df.columns[0], df.columns[-1]]) 
        if abbreviate_columns 
        else ', '.join(df.columns))
    columns = f"{len(df.columns)} entries: {_cols}"

    _typs = [
        col.dataType 
        for col in df.schema 
        if include_nested_types or (
            'ArrayType' not in str(col.dataType) and 
            'StructType' not in str(col.dataType) and
            'MapType' not in str(col.dataType))
    ]
    dtypes = ', '.join(
        f"{str(typ)}({cnt})" 
        for typ, cnt in Counter(_typs).items())

    mem = f'memory usage: ? bytes'

    return '\n'.join([classinfo, numrows, columns, dtypes, mem])
```

I wasn't sure about estimating size of pyspark dataframe. This depends on the full spark execution plan and configuration, but maybe try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46228385/5289570) for ideas.

Note that not all dtype summaries are included, by default nested types are excluded. Also `df.count()` is calculated, which can take a while, unless you calculate it first and pass it in.

Suggested usage:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(((1, 'a', 2),(2,'b',3)), ['id', 'letter', 'num'])
>>> print(spark_info(df, count=2))

<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
Total Rows: 2
3 entries: id, to num
LongType(2), StringType(1)
memory usage: ? bytes
```