# How to find count of Null and Nan values for each column in a PySpark dataframe efficiently?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
import numpy as np

data = [
    (1, 1, None), 
    (1, 2, float(5)), 
    (1, 3, np.nan), 
    (1, 4, None), 
    (1, 5, float(10)), 
    (1, 6, float("nan")), 
    (1, 6, float("nan")),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("session", "timestamp1", "id2"))
```

**Expected output**

dataframe with count of nan/null for each column

***Note:***
The previous questions I found in stack overflow only checks for null & not nan.
That's why I have created a new question.

I know I can use `isnull()` function in Spark to find number of Null values in Spark column but how to find Nan values in Spark dataframe?

Comment: Is there any solution for ```scala``` ?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You can use method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33900726) and replace `isNull` with `isnan`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, when, count, col

df.select([count(when(isnan(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
+-------+----------+---+
|session|timestamp1|id2|
+-------+----------+---+
|      0|         0|  3|
+-------+----------+---+
```

or

```
df.select([count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
+-------+----------+---+
|session|timestamp1|id2|
+-------+----------+---+
|      0|         0|  5|
+-------+----------+---+
```

Comment: [isNull](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=isnull#pyspark.sql.Column.isNull) vs [isnan](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=isnan#pyspark.sql.functions.isnan). These two links will help you. "isnan()" is a function of the pysparq.sql.function package, so you have to set which column you want to use as an argument of the function. "isNull()" belongs to pyspark.sql.Column package, so what you have to do is "yourColumn.isNull()"

Comment: I am getting an error with this df.select([count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()  - Is there any library I need to import. The error I am getting is illegal start of simple expression.

Comment: This solution does not work for timestamp columns

Comment: @EricBellet for timestamp columns you can utilized `df.dtypes`:
`df.select([f.count(f.when(f.isnan(c), c)).alias(c) for c, t in df.dtypes if t != "timestamp"]).show()`

Comment: scala equivalent: `df.select(df.columns.map(c => count(when(isnan(col(c)), c)).alias(c)):_*)`

Comment: scala: `df.select(df.columns.map(c => count(when(isnan(col(c)) || col(c).isNull, c)).alias(c)):_*).show()`

Answer (score 28):

For null values in the dataframe of pyspark

```
Dict_Null = {col:df.filter(df[col].isNull()).count() for col in df.columns}
Dict_Null

# The output in dict where key is column name and value is null values in that column

{'#': 0,
 'Name': 0,
 'Type 1': 0,
 'Type 2': 386,
 'Total': 0,
 'HP': 0,
 'Attack': 0,
 'Defense': 0,
 'Sp_Atk': 0,
 'Sp_Def': 0,
 'Speed': 0,
 'Generation': 0,
 'Legendary': 0}
```

Answer (score 17):

To make sure it does not fail for `string`, `date` and `timestamp` columns:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
def count_missings(spark_df,sort=True):
    """
    Counts number of nulls and nans in each column
    """
    df = spark_df.select([F.count(F.when(F.isnan(c) | F.isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for (c,c_type) in spark_df.dtypes if c_type not in ('timestamp', 'string', 'date')]).toPandas()

    if len(df) == 0:
        print("There are no any missing values!")
        return None

    if sort:
        return df.rename(index={0: 'count'}).T.sort_values("count",ascending=False)

    return df
```

If you want to see the columns sorted based on the number of nans and nulls in descending:

```py
count_missings(spark_df)

# | Col_A | 10 |
# | Col_C | 2  |
# | Col_B | 1  |
```

If you don't want ordering and see them as a single row:

```py
count_missings(spark_df, False)
# | Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
# |  10   |   1   |   2   |
```

Comment: This function is computationally expensive for large datasets.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: add 'boolean' and 'binary' to your not inexclusion list

Comment: Dangerous, because silently ignores `Null` in any of the excluded types.

Comment: Fails on PySpark 3 with 'float' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to the already provided ways is to simply filter on the column like so

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.where(F.col('columnNameHere').isNull())
```

This has the added benefit that you don't have to add another column to do the filtering and it's quick on larger data sets.

Comment: Overwrites df, maybe that not intended.  OP asks for count, should probably be `x.where(col(colname).isNull()).count()` for `x` a dframe and `colname` a string.

Comment: I might be missing something @pauljohn32 but it seems to me that your suggestion is exactly the same as my response, you just added the call to `count()` at the end. I think I am clear in my response that my code snippet shows how to do the filtering. Adding `df.count()` at the end should be considered a trivial addition. No?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my one liner.
Here 'c' is the name of the column

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, when, count, col, isNull
    
df.select('c').withColumn('isNull_c',F.col('c').isNull()).where('isNull_c = True').count()
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this solution:

```
df = spark.table(selected_table).filter(condition)

counter = df.count()

df = df.select([(counter - count(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn

# compatiable with fn.isnan. Sourced from
# https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/13fd272cd3/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L4818-L4836
NUMERIC_DTYPES = (
    'decimal',
    'double',
    'float',
    'int',
    'bigint',
    'smallilnt',
    'tinyint',
)


def count_nulls(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    isnan_compat_cols = {c for (c, t) in df.dtypes if any(t.startswith(num_dtype) for num_dtype in NUMERIC_DTYPES)}

    return df.select(
        [fn.count(fn.when(fn.isnan(c) | fn.isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in isnan_compat_cols]
        + [fn.count(fn.when(fn.isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in set(df.columns) - isnan_compat_cols]
    )
```

Builds off of gench and user8183279's answers, but checks via only `isnull` for columns where `isnan` is not possible, rather than just ignoring them.

The source code of `pyspark.sql.functions` [seemed to have the only documentation I could really find enumerating these names — if others know of some public docs  I'd be delighted](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/13fd272cd3/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L4818-L4836).

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing spark sql, then the following will also work to find null value and count subsequently.

`spark.sql('select * from table where isNULL(column_value)')`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative (improved upon Vamsi Krishna's solutions above):

```
def check_for_null_or_nan(df):
    null_or_nan = lambda x: isnan(x) | isnull(x)
    func = lambda x: df.filter(null_or_nan(x)).count()
    print(*[f'{i} has {func(i)} nans/nulls' for i in df.columns if func(i)!=0],sep='\n')
```

check_for_null_or_nan(df)

---

id2 has 5 nans/nulls

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to identify the null values in every columns using pyspark.

```
def check_nulls(dataframe):
    '''
    Check null values and return the null values in pandas Dataframe
    
    INPUT: Spark Dataframe
    OUTPUT: Null values
    
    '''
    # Create pandas dataframe
    nulls_check = pd.DataFrame(dataframe.select([count(when(isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in dataframe.columns]).collect(),
                               columns = dataframe.columns).transpose()
    nulls_check.columns = ['Null Values']
    return nulls_check

#Check null values
null_df = check_nulls(raw_df)
null_df
```

Comment: what happens if the data is 1TB in size? dont convert to pandas that defeats the purpose of using spark in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Here is a readable solution because code is for people as much as computers ;-)

```py
df.selectExpr('sum(int(isnull(<col_name>) or isnan(<col_name>))) as null_or_nan_count'))
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a method that avoids any pitfalls with `isnan` or `isNull` and works with any datatype

```py
# spark is a pyspark.sql.SparkSession object

def count_nulls(df: ):
    cache = df.cache()

    row_count = cache.count()
    return spark.createDataFrame(
        [[row_count - cache.select(col_name).na.drop().count() for col_name in cache.columns]],
        # schema=[(col_name, 'integer') for col_name in cache.columns]
        schema=cache.columns
    )
```