# How to drop all columns with null values in a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large dataset of which I would like to drop columns that contain `null` values and return a new dataframe. How can I do that?

The following only drops a single column or rows containing `null`.

```
df.where(col("dt_mvmt").isNull()) #doesnt work because I do not have all the columns names or for 1000's of columns
df.filter(df.dt_mvmt.isNotNull()) #same reason as above
df.na.drop() #drops rows that contain null, instead of columns that contain null
```

For example

```
a |  b  | c
1 |     | 0
2 |  2  | 3
```

In the above case it will drop the whole column `B` because one of its values is empty.

Comment: Trying checking - http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is one possible approach for dropping all columns that have NULL values: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627386/how-to-find-count-of-null-and-nan-values-for-each-column-in-a-pyspark-dataframe) for the source on the code of counting NULL values per column.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': ['a', '1', '2'],
                   'x2': ['b', None, '2'],
                   'x3': ['c', '0', '3'] })
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
df.show()

def drop_null_columns(df):
    """
    This function drops all columns which contain null values.
    :param df: A PySpark DataFrame
    """
    null_counts = df.select([F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
    to_drop = [k for k, v in null_counts.items() if v > 0]
    df = df.drop(*to_drop)
    return df

# Drops column b2, because it contains null values
drop_null_columns(df).show()
```

Before:

```
+---+----+---+
| x1|  x2| x3|
+---+----+---+
|  a|   b|  c|
|  1|null|  0|
|  2|   2|  3|
+---+----+---+
```

After:

```
+---+---+
| x1| x3|
+---+---+
|  a|  c|
|  1|  0|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes sir ! It did help. How beautiful ! The other 3 earlier lines also worked perfectly

Comment: Glad I could help! I removed the threshold-part, maybe a bit confusing to future people who stumble upon this question.

Comment: @Florian You should keep the threshold part, it makes it a complete answer! It would be really helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If we need to keep only the rows having at least one inspected column not null then use this. Execution time is very less.

````
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce

inspected = df.columns
df = df.where(reduce(or_, (F.col(c).isNotNull() for c in inspected ), F.lit(False)))```
````