# Quick way to delete empty column [PySpark]

Tags: pyspark, is-empty, col

Is there a easy way to drop empty column of a huge dataset (300+ col >100k row) in pyspark ? such as `df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')` in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322445/how-to-drop-all-columns-with-null-values-in-a-pyspark-dataframe/51325114#51325114). I've added a `threshold` parameter to it:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': ['a', '1', '2'],
                   'x2': ['b', None, '2'],
                   'x3': ['c', '0', '3'] })
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
df.show()

def drop_null_columns(df, threshold=0):
    """
    This function drops all columns which contain null values.
    :param df: A PySpark DataFrame
    """
    null_counts = df.select([F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
    to_drop = [k for k, v in null_counts.items() if v > threshold]
    df = df.drop(*to_drop)
    return df

# Drops column b2, because it contains null values
drop_null_columns(df).show()
```

#### Output

```
+---+---+
| x1| x3|
+---+---+
|  a|  c|
|  1|  0|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+
```

Column x2 has been dropped.

You can use `threshold=df.count()` to while using it

Comment: How do you change the function to delete the column only if all entries are null/nan/empty string?

Comment: @MachineLearner Here is a link for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51325114/8805315

Comment: Thank you for the provided link. But the provided solution gets rid of the second column which does not only consist of null but also has other values in it. I only want to remove the column if and only if all rows are null/nan/empty.

Comment: @MachineLearner let me do that for you

Comment: Sorry, I meant if and only if all rows are null/nan/emtpy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extended functionality of @pissall 's fn.:

```
def drop_null_columns(df, threshold=-1):
    """
    This function drops all columns which contain null values.
    If threshold is negative (default), drop columns that have only null values.
    If threshold is >=0, drop columns that have count of null values bigger than threshold. This may be very computationally expensive!
    Returns PySpark DataFrame.
    """
    if threshold<0:
        max_per_column = df.select([F.max(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
        to_drop = [k for k, v in max_per_column.items() if v == None]
    else:
        null_counts = df.select([F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
        to_drop = [k for k, v in null_counts.items() if v > threshold]
    df = df.drop(*to_drop)
    return df
```