# How to filter over all DataFrame columns of the same type with single request?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have large DataFrame with ±240 date and timestamp fields. Fields are nullable, nested, nested in arrays. And I want to find all column names with any date or timestamp value less than or greater than `X`. How to do this with single request?

**Example**

```
# DataFrame
name: Evgenii, born: 1998, father: [name: Ivan, born: 1970], wtf: [foo: bar, omg: [2000, 2001, 2022]]
name: Ivan, born: 1970, father: [name: Vasilii, born: 1940]
name: Vasilii, born: 1940, father: [name: Pavel, born: 1917]

# filter all columns with dates lt 1950 gives:
born, father.born

# filter all columns with dates lt 1920 gives:
father.born

# filter all columns with dates gt 1990 gives:
born, wtf.omg

(request must not contain column names)
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's some help to make this happen but not a complete code.

So getting a dataType is [pretty easy](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-find-datatype-column-names-of-dataframe/) at the top level of a dataframe. This would be easy to search for date or Timestamp.

> print(df.schema["name"].dataType)

If you want to explore a structs schema you need a small trick to get those:

> df.select("father.*").schema["name"]

See this link to see how to [drop columns with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322445/how-to-drop-all-columns-with-null-values-in-a-pyspark-dataframe).

> ````
> # Sample data df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': ['a', '1', '2'],
>                    'x2': ['b', None, '2'],
>                    'x3': ['c', '0', '3'] }) df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df) df.show()
>
> def drop_null_columns(df):
>     """
>     This function drops all columns which contain null values.
>     :param df: A PySpark DataFrame
>     """
>     null_counts = df.select([F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
>     to_drop = [k for k, v in null_counts.items() if v > 0]
>     df = df.drop(*to_drop)
>     return df
>
> # Drops column b2, because it contains null values drop_null_columns(df).show() ```
> ````