# How to improve performance of Pyspark method to get ratio of rows with missing data

Tags: performance, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do data validation on a large data set ~26 million rows by 36 columns to identify the ratio of missing data in columns. The current solution however is really slow and was wondering if anyone knew any ways to speed to optimize it?

I found and modified the method suggested here [How to find count of Null and Nan values for each column in a PySpark dataframe efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627386/how-to-find-count-of-null-and-nan-values-for-each-column-in-a-pyspark-dataframe) and it works but it is really slow for the large data set. I also tried using a pandas dataframe and it seemed to be more performant at smaller volumes but it just wouldn't scale up.

```
ratio_df = crm_df.select([(1 - (count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c))) / row_count).alias(c) for c in crm_df.columns])
```

Don't know if it is possible to improve performance but it is taking hours at present and would ideally like to get it down to less than an hour.

Comment: Example of input and desired output?

Comment: The code seem very performant already and I don't see how to improve it. Make sure your crm_df is cached (`crm_df.cache().count()`) before using the function and if it is still slow, increase your number of slaves in my opinion.