# Check if value greater than zero exists in all columns of dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
   data.select([count(when(isnan(c), c)).alias(c) for c in data.columns]).show()
```

This is the code I was trying to get the count of the nan values. I want to write an if-else condition where if a specific column contains nan values, I want to print the name of the column and count of nan values.

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627386/how-to-find-count-of-null-and-nan-values-for-each-column-in-a-pyspark-dataframe

Comment: How do I check for each column if nan is greater than 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to perform a **column** filtering first before passing it to the list comprehension.

For example, you have a df that looks as follows, where column c is **nan free**,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, count, when
import numpy as np

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1.0, np.nan, 0.0), (np.nan, 2.0, 9.0),\
                          (np.nan, 3.0, 8.0), (np.nan, 4.0, 7.0)], ('a', 'b', 'c'))

df.show()
# +---+---+---+
# |  a|  b|  c|
# +---+---+---+
# |1.0|NaN|0.0|
# |NaN|2.0|9.0|
# |NaN|3.0|8.0|
# |NaN|4.0|7.0|
# +---+---+---+
```

You were given the solutions and materials to produce

```
df.select([count(when((isnan(c)),c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
# +---+---+---+
# |  a|  b|  c|
# +---+---+---+
# |  3|  1|  0|
# +---+---+---+
```

but you want

```
# +---+---+
# |  a|  b|
# +---+---+
# |  3|  1|
# +---+---+
```

In order to have that output, you can try this

```
rows = df.collect()

#column filtering based on your nan condition
nan_columns = [''.join(key) for _ in rows  for (key,val) in _.asDict().items() if np.isnan(val)]

nan_columns = list(set(nan_columns)) #may sort if order is important
#nan_columns
#['a', 'b']

df.select([count(when((isnan(c)),c)).alias(c) for c in nan_columns]).show()
# +---+---+
# |  a|  b|
# +---+---+
# |  3|  1|
# +---+---+
```

Comment: It seems it's slow by using `df.collect()`. It's there a better way?

Comment: @rosefun If you want to avoid the use of df.collect() on a large data set with many rows, then I would suggest obtain the output in the second code block first, for example, with a select statement. Second, perform conditional filtering to drop the column with zero on that single-row dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

You can just convert the same comprehension to:

```
df.select([count(when(c > 0, c)).alias(c) for c in data.columns]).show()
```

but this will cause problems when you have other `dtypes`.
So let's go with:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
# You can do the following two lines of code in one line, but want to make it more readable
schema = {col: col_type for col, col_type in df.dtypes}
numeric_columns = [
            col for col, col_type in schema.items()
            if col_type in "int double bitint".split()
        ]

df.select([count(when(col(c) > 0, c)).alias(c) for c in numeric_columns]).show()
```