# Pyspark: Need to show a count of null/empty values per each column in a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe and need to do a count of null/empty values for each column. I need to show ALL columns in the output. I have looked online and found a few "**similar questions**" but the solutions totally blew my mind which is why I am posting here for personal help.

Here is what I have for code, I know this part of the puzzle.

```
from pyspark.sql import *

sf.isnull()
```

After running it, this is the error I receive  `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isnull'`

What's interesting is that, I did the same exercise with pandas and used  `df.isna().sum()` which worked great. What am I missing for pyspark?

Comment: Are you sure that a data frame (in pyspark.syl, not pandas) has such a method: [From the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/search.html?q=isnull)

Comment: this is where I am confused, I dont know. I clicked on your link and see `pyspark.sql.Column.isNull ` Then I went further and as an example its show `filter` is being used. I have no clue what that even is.

Comment: But a `Column` isn't a `DataFrame`: "Column: A column expression _in_ a DataFrame"?

Comment: there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627386/how-to-find-count-of-null-and-nan-values-for-each-column-in-a-pyspark-dataframe) already

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find count of Null and Nan values for each column in a PySpark dataframe efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627386/how-to-find-count-of-null-and-nan-values-for-each-column-in-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following, just make sure your df is a Spark DataFrame.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df.select(*(count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns)).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below, but make sure df should be your Spark DataFrame

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, count

df.select(*(count(when(col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns)).show()
```