# Efficient way to find columns that contain ANY null values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to return a list of all columns that contain at least 1 null value. All of the other similar questions I have seen on StackOverflow are filtering the column where the value is null, but this is definitely sub-optimal since it has to find ALL the null values, but I just want to find ONE null value.

I could filter the column where the value is null, and then if the count of this result is greater than 1, then I know the column contains a null value. However, as I said this is suboptimal as it first finds all null values.

Is there any way to do this?

Furthermore, is there any way to do this without looping over all the columns?

Comment: Seems hard. Maybe transposing your data and summing over? Could this be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627386/how-to-find-count-of-null-and-nan-values-for-each-column-in-a-pyspark-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark's SQL function [any](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#any) can check if any value of a column meets a condition.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [[1,2,3],[None, 5, 6], [7, None, 9]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["col1", "col2", "col3"])

cols = [f"any({col} is null) as {col}_contains_null" for col in df.columns]
df.selectExpr(cols).show()
```

Output:

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|col1_contains_null|col2_contains_null|col3_contains_null|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|              true|              true|             false|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking for the column names that contain any null value you may try this -

```
cols_with_nulls = [x for x in df.columns if df.filter(F.col(x).isNull()).count() > 0]
```