# Counting nulls or zeros in PySpark data frame with struct column types

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a PySpark data frame that has a mix of integer columns, string columns, and also struct columns. A struct column could be a struct, but it could also just be `null`. For example:

```
id | mystring   |  mystruct |
-------------------------- 
1  | something  | <struct>|
2  | something  | null    |
3  | 0          | null    |
4  | something  | null    |
5  | something  | <struct> |
```

Is there any easy way to go through the entire data frame and get the count of null/na/0 values without having to explode the struct columns? For example, I would want for above

```
id | mystring   |  mystruct |
-------------------------- 
0  | 1          | 3
```

I've seen a few different methods but they always seem to throw an error with the struct types, and I'd rather not have to do them separately.

Comment: I think you can use the conditional count by `count(when(...))`, what is your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find count of Null and Nan values for each column in a PySpark dataframe efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627386/how-to-find-count-of-null-and-nan-values-for-each-column-in-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an easy way, but you could define a function to handle the `nulls` (all input types) and `nans`/`zeros` (for numeric inputs) for each column. Then you can join the results for each column separately.

```py
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

# setup
data = [[1, {'f':[1,2,3]}], [2, None],[0, None], [1, None], [3, {'f':[1]}]]
schema = StructType([
    StructField('mynum', IntegerType(), True), 
    StructField('mystruct', 
        StructType([StructField('f', ArrayType(IntegerType()), True)]), True)
    ])
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

def get_nulls_nans_zeros(c, df):
    # all inputs
    val = df.select(count(when(isnull(c), c)).alias(c))
    t = type(df.schema[c].dataType)
    # numeric inputs
    if t in [ByteType, ShortType, IntegerType, LongType, FloatType, DoubleType, DecimalType]:
        val = val.union(df.select(count(when(isnan(c), c)).alias(c)))
        val = val.union(df.select(count(when(col(c) == 0, c)).alias(c)))
    return val.select(sum(c).alias(c))

# Get and merge results for each column
res = [get_nulls_nans_zeros(c, df) for c in df.columns]
res = [r.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id()) for r in res]
result = res[0].join(res[1], "id", "outer").drop("id")
result.show()
```

If you're using Spark 3.1+, you can also use the `allowMissingColumns` flag in `unionByName` to do the last part instead of having to join via a monotonically increasing id.