Get all the columns in a PySpark dataframe whose value is not 0.0
I am trying to learn PySpark. I am using a dummy dataset and practicing some basic data pre-processing techniques such as dealing with NaN values. The problem I am encountering is I cannot seem for filter out the columns in which no NaN values are present.
df_nan_values = df.select([(count(when(col(c)=="NA",c))/count(col(c))).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
NaN values are signified with "NA" string. This returns me a 1 row n column dataframe with the values signifying the ratio of "NA" in the column against the length of the column.
My expected behavior in Pandas:
pddf = pd.read_csv(path)
nan_ratio_df = pd.DataFrame(pddf.isna().sum()/len(pddf.index))
nan_ratio_df = nan_ratio_df.loc[nan_ratio_df[0]>0.50]
nan_cols_filtered = nan_ratio_df.index.tolist()

This gives me list of columns whose NaN ratio is greater than 0.50.

Duplicated from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627386/how-to-find-count-of-null-and-nan-values-for-each-column-in-a-pyspark-dataframe

Please provide as sample input and expected output.
