# How to find pyspark dataframe memory usage?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

For python dataframe, info() function provides memory usage.
Is there any equivalent in pyspark ?
Thanks

Comment: http://metricbrew.com/how-to-estimate-rdd-or-dataframe-real-size-in-pyspark/

Comment: @MaxU whats the unit of memory usage in this program.

Comment: [# of bytes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/util/SizeEstimator.html)

Answer (score 20):

Try to use [the `_to_java_object_rdd()` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/common.html):

```
import py4j.protocol  
from py4j.protocol import Py4JJavaError  
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaObject  
from py4j.java_collections import JavaArray, JavaList

from pyspark import RDD, SparkContext  
from pyspark.serializers import PickleSerializer, AutoBatchedSerializer

# your dataframe what you'd estimate
df

# Helper function to convert python object to Java objects
def _to_java_object_rdd(rdd):  
    """ Return a JavaRDD of Object by unpickling
    It will convert each Python object into Java object by Pyrolite, whenever the
    RDD is serialized in batch or not.
    """
    rdd = rdd._reserialize(AutoBatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer()))
    return rdd.ctx._jvm.org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe.pythonToJava(rdd._jrdd, True)

# First you have to convert it to an RDD 
JavaObj = _to_java_object_rdd(df.rdd)

# Now we can run the estimator
sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator.estimate(JavaObj)
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU  ..is there any shorter way to do this? I did not get most part of this program.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am unable to open the link given above. What is the unit of the return data size??

Comment: [Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/util/SizeEstimator.html) of `SizeEstimator` says, it calculates JVM heap size of the objects occupied on each executor. Are there any caveats to using this method? DO i need to persist or cache the dataframe before running this? How much variance can i expect in the results. I ran it on a big dataframe where the estimated size varies from 500 to 1400 MBs.

Comment: Does this work? When I run this on objects with very different sizes, I get similar answers (to within a couple of percent). Also, if I run it on the same object twice, the answer changes by a couple of percent.

Answer (score 18):

I have something in mind, its just a rough estimation. as far as i know spark doesn't have a straight forward way to get dataframe memory usage, But Pandas dataframe does. so what you can do is.

1. select 1% of data `sample = df.sample(fraction = 0.01)`
2. `pdf = sample.toPandas()`
3. get pandas dataframe memory usage by `pdf.info()`
4. Multiply that values by 100, this should give a rough estimate of your whole spark dataframe memory usage.
5. Correct me if i am wrong :|

Comment: This seems reasonable and should provide a conservative estimate. I am not sure about time costs and whether this is any faster than .cache() and checking the storage under spark ui, however.

Comment: I think so far the most suitable solution. Only fraction value is dependent on the data volume that you are using. Other than that, perfect.

Comment: This answer overloads the driver. Spark DataFrame is a distributed data structure, when you convert it to pandas it moves data around and might shutdown your driver.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-tuning):

> The best way to size the amount of memory consumption a dataset will require is to create an RDD, put it into cache, and look at the “Storage” page in the web UI. The page will tell you how much memory the RDD is occupying.
>
> To estimate the memory consumption of a particular object, use SizeEstimator’s estimate method. This is useful for experimenting with different data layouts to trim memory usage, as well as determining the amount of space a broadcast variable will occupy on each executor heap.

Answer (score 1):

For the dataframe df you can do this:

```
sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator.estimate(df._jdf)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can persist dataframe in memory and take action as df.count(). You would be able to check the size under storage tab on spark web ui.. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RepartiPy](https://github.com/sakjung/repartipy) to get the accurate size of your DataFrame as follows:

```py
import repartipy

# Use this if you have enough (executor) memory to cache the whole DataFrame
# If you have NOT enough memory (i.e. too large DataFrame), use 'repartipy.SamplingSizeEstimator' instead.
with repartipy.SizeEstimator(spark=spark, df=df) as se:
    df_size_in_bytes = se.estimate()
```

RepartiPy leverages [Caching Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49529028/12982476) internally, in order to calculate the in-memory size of your DataFrame.

Please see the [docs](https://github.com/sakjung/repartipy?tab=readme-ov-file#repartipy) for more details.

Answer (score -5):

How about below? It's in KB, X100 to get the estimated real size.

```
df.sample(fraction = 0.01).cache().count()
```

Comment: This is not in KB, this will return only row count

Comment: No, it is only selecting a random 1% data of whole data. and then its row count